# How to check if a field (multiple occurrence in XML) is having a value from the predefined set of values using Xpath

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I have an XML where I am trying to check following conditions -

1. If Count of E1KNVVM segments > 0 then do the following, else set false.
2. If KTOKD = Z002|Z004 - Set false. No need to check VKORG. else check the following
3. If there is atleast one E1KNVVM segment with VKORG = 1000|1010|1140|1150|1060 - set true.
4. if all the VKORG = 1140 and KTOKD = Z012|Z013, set false. if all the VKORG = 1140 and KTOKD != Z012|Z013, set true
5. if all the VKORG = 1060 and KTOKD = Z012|Z013, set false. if all the VKORG = 1060 and KTOKD != Z012|Z013, set true
6. If KTOKD = Z012|Z013 and there is at least one VKORG = 1000|1010|1150 - set true.

Example data -
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ZOMI034_DEBMAS07>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
        
        <E1KNA1M SEGMENT="1">
            <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
            <KUNNR>0010015829</KUNNR>
            <BBBNR>0000000</BBBNR>
            <BBSNR>00000</BBSNR>
            <BUBKZ>0</BUBKZ>
            <KTOKD>Z012</KTOKD>
            <LAND1>CA</LAND1>
            <NAME1>Decoration Sherbrooke Inc</NAME1>
            <NAME3>Decoration Sherbrooke Inc</NAME3>
            <ORT01>Sherbrooke</ORT01>
            <PSTLZ>J1J 4L9</PSTLZ>
            <REGIO>QC</REGIO>
            <SORTL>DECORATION</SORTL>
            <SPRAS>E</SPRAS>
            <STRAS>739 rue Paul-Desruisseaux</STRAS>
            <TELF1>819-566-5585</TELF1>
            <TELFX>819-565-0855</TELFX>
            <LZONE>J1J</LZONE>
            <UMJAH>0000</UMJAH>
            <JMZAH>000000</JMZAH>
            <JMJAH>0000</JMJAH>
            <KATR1>TP</KATR1>
            <KATR2>DL</KATR2>
            <KATR3>SF</KATR3>
            <KATR4>OS</KATR4>
            <KATR5>SW</KATR5>
            <KATR9>001</KATR9>
            <KATR10>074</KATR10>
            <UMSA1>0</UMSA1>
            <HZUOR>00</HZUOR>
            <CIVVE>X</CIVVE>
            <SPRAS_ISO>EN</SPRAS_ISO>
            <KDKG1>S</KDKG>
            <E1KNVVM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <VKORG>11409</VKORG>
                <VTWEG>01</VTWEG>
                <SPART>00</SPART>
                <VERSG>1</VERSG>
                <AUFSD>01</AUFSD>
                <KALKS>1</KALKS>
                <KDGRP>N</KDGRP>
                <BZIRK>SOM014</BZIRK>
                <KONDA>ID</KONDA>
                <PLTYP>22</PLTYP>
                <AWAHR>100</AWAHR>
                <INCO1>PPD</INCO1>
                <INCO2>Mississauga</INCO2>
                <ANTLF>9</ANTLF>
                <LPRIO>03</LPRIO>
                <VSBED>01</VSBED>
                <FAKSD>25</FAKSD>
                <WAERS>CAD</WAERS>
                <KTGRD>01</KTGRD>
                <ZTERM>H013</ZTERM>
                <VKGRP>BC1</VKGRP>
                <VKBUR>WT</VKBUR>
                <KVGR1>ID</KVGR1>
                <KVGR2>05</KVGR2>
                <KVGR4>FAB</KVGR4>
                <KVGR5>NE</KVGR5>
                <BOKRE>X</BOKRE>
                <PRFRE>X</PRFRE>
                <KABSS>ZCCP</KABSS>
                <UEBTO>10.0</UEBTO>
                <UNTTO>15.0</UNTTO>
                <PODTG>         0</PODTG>
                <INCO2_L>Mississauga</INCO2_L>
                <KALKS_NEW>1</KALKS_NEW>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>YG</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000600419</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>YD</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000600257</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>WE</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0010015829</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>AG</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0010015829</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>RG</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0010015829</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>RE</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0010015829</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>YR</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000600323</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>Z4</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000165083</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>Y1</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000107886</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>Z6</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000165083</KUNN2>
                    <KNREF>50166531</KNREF>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>Z8</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000165083</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVIM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <ALAND>US</ALAND>
                    <TATYP>ZITD</TATYP>
                    <TAXKD>1</TAXKD>
                </E1KNVIM>
                <E1KNVIM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <ALAND>CA</ALAND>
                    <TATYP>ZITD</TATYP>
                    <TAXKD>1</TAXKD>
                </E1KNVIM>
                <E1KNVIM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <ALAND>MX</ALAND>
                    <TATYP>ZITD</TATYP>
                    <TAXKD>1</TAXKD>
                </E1KNVIM>
            </E1KNVVM>
            <E1KNVVM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <VKORG>1140</VKORG>
                <VTWEG>01</VTWEG>
                <SPART>00</SPART>
                <VERSG>1</VERSG>
                <AUFSD>01</AUFSD>
                <KALKS>1</KALKS>
                <KDGRP>N</KDGRP>
                <BZIRK>T00376</BZIRK>
                <KONDA>ID</KONDA>
                <PLTYP>03</PLTYP>
                <AWAHR>100</AWAHR>
                <INCO1>PPD</INCO1>
                <INCO2>MISSISSAUGA</INCO2>
                <ANTLF>9</ANTLF>
                <LPRIO>03</LPRIO>
                <VSBED>01</VSBED>
                <FAKSD>25</FAKSD>
                <WAERS>CAD</WAERS>
                <KTGRD>01</KTGRD>
                <ZTERM>H013</ZTERM>
                <VKGRP>Q1</VKGRP>
                <VKBUR>QC</VKBUR>
                <KVGR1>ID</KVGR1>
                <KVGR2>OT</KVGR2>
                <KVGR4>FAB</KVGR4>
                <KVGR5>NE</KVGR5>
                <BOKRE>X</BOKRE>
                <PRFRE>X</PRFRE>
                <KABSS>ZCCP</KABSS>
                <UEBTO>10.0</UEBTO>
                <UNTTO>15.0</UNTTO>
                <PODTG>         0</PODTG>
                <INCO2_L>MISSISSAUGA</INCO2_L>
                <KALKS_NEW>1</KALKS_NEW>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>YG</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000600311</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>YR</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000600320</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>YD</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000600256</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>WE</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0010015829</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>AG</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0010015829</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>RG</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0010015829</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>RE</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0010015829</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>Z4</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000165083</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>Y1</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000107887</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>Z8</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000165083</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVIM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <ALAND>US</ALAND>
                    <TATYP>ZITD</TATYP>
                    <TAXKD>1</TAXKD>
                </E1KNVIM>
                <E1KNVIM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <ALAND>CA</ALAND>
                    <TATYP>ZITD</TATYP>
                    <TAXKD>1</TAXKD>
                </E1KNVIM>
                <E1KNVIM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <ALAND>MX</ALAND>
                    <TATYP>ZITD</TATYP>
                    <TAXKD>1</TAXKD>
                </E1KNVIM>
                <E1KNVVH SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <TDOBJECT>KNVV</TDOBJECT>
                    <TDNAME>001001582910100100</TDNAME>
                    <TDID>0001</TDID>
                    <TDSPRAS>E</TDSPRAS>
                    <TDSPRASISO>EN</TDSPRASISO>
                    <E1KNVVL SEGMENT="1">
                        <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                        <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
                        <TDLINE>TAKE NO ORDERS FROM BRIGETTE LAGACE</TDLINE>
                    </E1KNVVL>
                </E1KNVVH>
            </E1KNVVM>
            <E1KNVVM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <VKORG>1192</VKORG>
                <VTWEG>01</VTWEG>
                <SPART>00</SPART>
                <VERSG>1</VERSG>
                <AUFSD>01</AUFSD>
                <KALKS>1</KALKS>
                <KDGRP>N</KDGRP>
                <BZIRK>T00376</BZIRK>
                <KONDA>ID</KONDA>
                <PLTYP>03</PLTYP>
                <AWAHR>100</AWAHR>
                <INCO1>PPD</INCO1>
                <INCO2>MISSISSAUGA</INCO2>
                <ANTLF>9</ANTLF>
                <LPRIO>03</LPRIO>
                <VSBED>01</VSBED>
                <FAKSD>25</FAKSD>
                <WAERS>CAD</WAERS>
                <KTGRD>01</KTGRD>
                <ZTERM>H013</ZTERM>
                <VKGRP>Q1</VKGRP>
                <VKBUR>QC</VKBUR>
                <KVGR1>ID</KVGR1>
                <KVGR2>OT</KVGR2>
                <KVGR4>FAB</KVGR4>
                <KVGR5>NE</KVGR5>
                <BOKRE>X</BOKRE>
                <PRFRE>X</PRFRE>
                <KABSS>ZCCP</KABSS>
                <UEBTO>10.0</UEBTO>
                <UNTTO>15.0</UNTTO>
                <PODTG>         0</PODTG>
                <INCO2_L>MISSISSAUGA</INCO2_L>
                <KALKS_NEW>1</KALKS_NEW>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>YG</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000600311</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>YR</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000600320</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>YD</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000600256</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>WE</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0010015829</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>AG</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0010015829</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>RG</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0010015829</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>RE</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0010015829</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>Z4</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000165083</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>Y1</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000107887</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVPM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <PARVW>Z8</PARVW>
                    <KUNN2>0000165083</KUNN2>
                    <PARZA>000</PARZA>
                </E1KNVPM>
                <E1KNVIM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <ALAND>US</ALAND>
                    <TATYP>ZITD</TATYP>
                    <TAXKD>1</TAXKD>
                </E1KNVIM>
                <E1KNVIM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <ALAND>CA</ALAND>
                    <TATYP>ZITD</TATYP>
                    <TAXKD>1</TAXKD>
                </E1KNVIM>
                <E1KNVIM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <ALAND>MX</ALAND>
                    <TATYP>ZITD</TATYP>
                    <TAXKD>1</TAXKD>
                </E1KNVIM>
                <E1KNVVH SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <TDOBJECT>KNVV</TDOBJECT>
                    <TDNAME>001001582910100100</TDNAME>
                    <TDID>0001</TDID>
                    <TDSPRAS>E</TDSPRAS>
                    <TDSPRASISO>EN</TDSPRASISO>
                    <E1KNVVL SEGMENT="1">
                        <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                        <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
                        <TDLINE>TAKE NO ORDERS FROM BRIGETTE LAGACE</TDLINE>
                    </E1KNVVL>
                </E1KNVVH>
            </E1KNVVM>
            <E1KNB1M SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <BUKRS>1222</BUKRS>
                <BUSAB>EM</BUSAB>
                <AKONT>0000121000</AKONT>
                <ZWELS>YZX</ZWELS>
                <ZTERM>H013</ZTERM>
                <ZINDT>20091201</ZINDT>
                <ZINRT>01</ZINRT>
                <ZSABE>MIREILLE</ZSABE>
                <VLIBB>0</VLIBB>
                <VRSZL>0</VRSZL>
                <VRSPR>0</VRSPR>
                <VERDT>00000000</VERDT>
                <XAUSZ>1</XAUSZ>
                <WEBTR>0</WEBTR>
                <DATLZ>19000101</DATLZ>
                <XZVER>X</XZVER>
                <KULTG>0</KULTG>
                <PERNR>00000000</PERNR>
                <INTAD>leblancmir@gmail.com</INTAD>
            </E1KNB1M>
            <E1KNB1M SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <BUKRS>1227</BUKRS>
                <BUSAB>EM</BUSAB>
                <AKONT>0000121000</AKONT>
                <ZWELS>YZX</ZWELS>
                <ZTERM>H013</ZTERM>
                <ZINDT>19000101</ZINDT>
                <ZINRT>01</ZINRT>
                <ZSABE>Mireille L.</ZSABE>
                <VLIBB>0</VLIBB>
                <VRSZL>0</VRSZL>
                <VRSPR>0</VRSPR>
                <VERDT>00000000</VERDT>
                <XAUSZ>2</XAUSZ>
                <WEBTR>0</WEBTR>
                <DATLZ>19000101</DATLZ>
                <XZVER>X</XZVER>
                <KULTG>0</KULTG>
                <PERNR>00000000</PERNR>
                <INTAD>leblancmir@gmail.com</INTAD>
            </E1KNB1M>
            <E1KNVKM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <PARNR>0000107886</PARNR>
                <NAME1>Invoice Recipient 1</NAME1>
                <UEPAR>0000000000</UEPAR>
                <PARLA>E</PARLA>
                <GBDAT>00000000</GBDAT>
                <VRTNR>0000000000</VRTNR>
                <MOAB1>000000</MOAB1>
                <MOBI1>000000</MOBI1>
                <MOAB2>000000</MOAB2>
                <MOBI2>000000</MOBI2>
                <DIAB1>000000</DIAB1>
                <DIBI1>000000</DIBI1>
                <DIAB2>000000</DIAB2>
                <DIBI2>000000</DIBI2>
                <MIAB1>000000</MIAB1>
                <MIBI1>000000</MIBI1>
                <MIAB2>000000</MIAB2>
                <MIBI2>000000</MIBI2>
                <DOAB1>000000</DOAB1>
                <DOBI1>000000</DOBI1>
                <DOAB2>000000</DOAB2>
                <DOBI2>000000</DOBI2>
                <FRAB1>000000</FRAB1>
                <FRBI1>000000</FRBI1>
                <FRAB2>000000</FRAB2>
                <FRBI2>000000</FRBI2>
                <SAAB1>000000</SAAB1>
                <SABI1>000000</SABI1>
                <SAAB2>000000</SAAB2>
                <SABI2>000000</SABI2>
                <SOAB1>000000</SOAB1>
                <SOBI1>000000</SOBI1>
                <SOAB2>000000</SOAB2>
                <SOBI2>000000</SOBI2>
                <PARLA_ISO>EN</PARLA_ISO>
            </E1KNVKM>
            <E1KNVKM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <PARNR>0000107887</PARNR>
                <NAME1>Invoice Recipient 1</NAME1>
                <UEPAR>0000000000</UEPAR>
                <PARLA>E</PARLA>
                <GBDAT>00000000</GBDAT>
                <VRTNR>0000000000</VRTNR>
                <MOAB1>000000</MOAB1>
                <MOBI1>000000</MOBI1>
                <MOAB2>000000</MOAB2>
                <MOBI2>000000</MOBI2>
                <DIAB1>000000</DIAB1>
                <DIBI1>000000</DIBI1>
                <DIAB2>000000</DIAB2>
                <DIBI2>000000</DIBI2>
                <MIAB1>000000</MIAB1>
                <MIBI1>000000</MIBI1>
                <MIAB2>000000</MIAB2>
                <MIBI2>000000</MIBI2>
                <DOAB1>000000</DOAB1>
                <DOBI1>000000</DOBI1>
                <DOAB2>000000</DOAB2>
                <DOBI2>000000</DOBI2>
                <FRAB1>000000</FRAB1>
                <FRBI1>000000</FRBI1>
                <FRAB2>000000</FRAB2>
                <FRBI2>000000</FRBI2>
                <SAAB1>000000</SAAB1>
                <SABI1>000000</SABI1>
                <SAAB2>000000</SAAB2>
                <SABI2>000000</SABI2>
                <SOAB1>000000</SOAB1>
                <SOBI1>000000</SOBI1>
                <SOAB2>000000</SOAB2>
                <SOBI2>000000</SOBI2>
                <PARLA_ISO>EN</PARLA_ISO>
            </E1KNVKM>
            <E1KNVKM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <PARNR>0000107888</PARNR>
                <NAME1>Invoice Recipient 1</NAME1>
                <UEPAR>0000000000</UEPAR>
                <PARLA>E</PARLA>
                <GBDAT>00000000</GBDAT>
                <VRTNR>0000000000</VRTNR>
                <MOAB1>000000</MOAB1>
                <MOBI1>000000</MOBI1>
                <MOAB2>000000</MOAB2>
                <MOBI2>000000</MOBI2>
                <DIAB1>000000</DIAB1>
                <DIBI1>000000</DIBI1>
                <DIAB2>000000</DIAB2>
                <DIBI2>000000</DIBI2>
                <MIAB1>000000</MIAB1>
                <MIBI1>000000</MIBI1>
                <MIAB2>000000</MIAB2>
                <MIBI2>000000</MIBI2>
                <DOAB1>000000</DOAB1>
                <DOBI1>000000</DOBI1>
                <DOAB2>000000</DOAB2>
                <DOBI2>000000</DOBI2>
                <FRAB1>000000</FRAB1>
                <FRBI1>000000</FRBI1>
                <FRAB2>000000</FRAB2>
                <FRBI2>000000</FRBI2>
                <SAAB1>000000</SAAB1>
                <SABI1>000000</SABI1>
                <SAAB2>000000</SAAB2>
                <SABI2>000000</SABI2>
                <SOAB1>000000</SOAB1>
                <SOBI1>000000</SOBI1>
                <SOAB2>000000</SOAB2>
                <SOBI2>000000</SOBI2>
                <PARLA_ISO>EN</PARLA_ISO>
            </E1KNVKM>
            <E1KNVKM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <PARNR>0000107889</PARNR>
                <NAME1>Invoice Recipient 1</NAME1>
                <UEPAR>0000000000</UEPAR>
                <PARLA>E</PARLA>
                <GBDAT>00000000</GBDAT>
                <VRTNR>0000000000</VRTNR>
                <MOAB1>000000</MOAB1>
                <MOBI1>000000</MOBI1>
                <MOAB2>000000</MOAB2>
                <MOBI2>000000</MOBI2>
                <DIAB1>000000</DIAB1>
                <DIBI1>000000</DIBI1>
                <DIAB2>000000</DIAB2>
                <DIBI2>000000</DIBI2>
                <MIAB1>000000</MIAB1>
                <MIBI1>000000</MIBI1>
                <MIAB2>000000</MIAB2>
                <MIBI2>000000</MIBI2>
                <DOAB1>000000</DOAB1>
                <DOBI1>000000</DOBI1>
                <DOAB2>000000</DOAB2>
                <DOBI2>000000</DOBI2>
                <FRAB1>000000</FRAB1>
                <FRBI1>000000</FRBI1>
                <FRAB2>000000</FRAB2>
                <FRBI2>000000</FRBI2>
                <SAAB1>000000</SAAB1>
                <SABI1>000000</SABI1>
                <SAAB2>000000</SAAB2>
                <SABI2>000000</SABI2>
                <SOAB1>000000</SOAB1>
                <SOBI1>000000</SOBI1>
                <SOAB2>000000</SOAB2>
                <SOBI2>000000</SOBI2>
                <PARLA_ISO>EN</PARLA_ISO>
            </E1KNVKM>
            <E1KNVKM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <PARNR>0000165083</PARNR>
                <NAMEV>General</NAMEV>
                <NAME1>Confirmation</NAME1>
                <UEPAR>0000000000</UEPAR>
                <PARLA>E</PARLA>
                <GBDAT>00000000</GBDAT>
                <VRTNR>0000000000</VRTNR>
                <MOAB1>000000</MOAB1>
                <MOBI1>000000</MOBI1>
                <MOAB2>000000</MOAB2>
                <MOBI2>000000</MOBI2>
                <DIAB1>000000</DIAB1>
                <DIBI1>000000</DIBI1>
                <DIAB2>000000</DIAB2>
                <DIBI2>000000</DIBI2>
                <MIAB1>000000</MIAB1>
                <MIBI1>000000</MIBI1>
                <MIAB2>000000</MIAB2>
                <MIBI2>000000</MIBI2>
                <DOAB1>000000</DOAB1>
                <DOBI1>000000</DOBI1>
                <DOAB2>000000</DOAB2>
                <DOBI2>000000</DOBI2>
                <FRAB1>000000</FRAB1>
                <FRBI1>000000</FRBI1>
                <FRAB2>000000</FRAB2>
                <FRBI2>000000</FRBI2>
                <SAAB1>000000</SAAB1>
                <SABI1>000000</SABI1>
                <SAAB2>000000</SAAB2>
                <SABI2>000000</SABI2>
                <SOAB1>000000</SOAB1>
                <SOBI1>000000</SOBI1>
                <SOAB2>000000</SOAB2>
                <SOBI2>000000</SOBI2>
                <PARLA_ISO>EN</PARLA_ISO>
            </E1KNVKM>
            <E1KNVKM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <PARNR>0000165084</PARNR>
                <NAMEV>General</NAMEV>
                <NAME1>Confirmation</NAME1>
                <UEPAR>0000000000</UEPAR>
                <PARLA>E</PARLA>
                <GBDAT>00000000</GBDAT>
                <VRTNR>0000000000</VRTNR>
                <MOAB1>000000</MOAB1>
                <MOBI1>000000</MOBI1>
                <MOAB2>000000</MOAB2>
                <MOBI2>000000</MOBI2>
                <DIAB1>000000</DIAB1>
                <DIBI1>000000</DIBI1>
                <DIAB2>000000</DIAB2>
                <DIBI2>000000</DIBI2>
                <MIAB1>000000</MIAB1>
                <MIBI1>000000</MIBI1>
                <MIAB2>000000</MIAB2>
                <MIBI2>000000</MIBI2>
                <DOAB1>000000</DOAB1>
                <DOBI1>000000</DOBI1>
                <DOAB2>000000</DOAB2>
                <DOBI2>000000</DOBI2>
                <FRAB1>000000</FRAB1>
                <FRBI1>000000</FRBI1>
                <FRAB2>000000</FRAB2>
                <FRBI2>000000</FRBI2>
                <SAAB1>000000</SAAB1>
                <SABI1>000000</SABI1>
                <SAAB2>000000</SAAB2>
                <SABI2>000000</SABI2>
                <SOAB1>000000</SOAB1>
                <SOBI1>000000</SOBI1>
                <SOAB2>000000</SOAB2>
                <SOBI2>000000</SOBI2>
                <PARLA_ISO>EN</PARLA_ISO>
            </E1KNVKM>
            <E1KNVKM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <PARNR>0000055761</PARNR>
                <NAME1>ACKNOWLEDGMENT</NAME1>
                <UEPAR>0000000000</UEPAR>
                <PARLA>E</PARLA>
                <GBDAT>00000000</GBDAT>
                <VRTNR>0000000000</VRTNR>
                <MOAB1>000000</MOAB1>
                <MOBI1>000000</MOBI1>
                <MOAB2>000000</MOAB2>
                <MOBI2>000000</MOBI2>
                <DIAB1>000000</DIAB1>
                <DIBI1>000000</DIBI1>
                <DIAB2>000000</DIAB2>
                <DIBI2>000000</DIBI2>
                <MIAB1>000000</MIAB1>
                <MIBI1>000000</MIBI1>
                <MIAB2>000000</MIAB2>
                <MIBI2>000000</MIBI2>
                <DOAB1>000000</DOAB1>
                <DOBI1>000000</DOBI1>
                <DOAB2>000000</DOAB2>
                <DOBI2>000000</DOBI2>
                <FRAB1>000000</FRAB1>
                <FRBI1>000000</FRBI1>
                <FRAB2>000000</FRAB2>
                <FRBI2>000000</FRBI2>
                <SAAB1>000000</SAAB1>
                <SABI1>000000</SABI1>
                <SAAB2>000000</SAAB2>
                <SABI2>000000</SABI2>
                <SOAB1>000000</SOAB1>
                <SOBI1>000000</SOBI1>
                <SOAB2>000000</SOAB2>
                <SOBI2>000000</SOBI2>
                <PARLA_ISO>EN</PARLA_ISO>
            </E1KNVKM>
            <E1KNVKM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <PARNR>0000055765</PARNR>
                <NAME1>ASN</NAME1>
                <UEPAR>0000000000</UEPAR>
                <PARLA>E</PARLA>
                <GBDAT>00000000</GBDAT>
                <VRTNR>0000000000</VRTNR>
                <MOAB1>000000</MOAB1>
                <MOBI1>000000</MOBI1>
                <MOAB2>000000</MOAB2>
                <MOBI2>000000</MOBI2>
                <DIAB1>000000</DIAB1>
                <DIBI1>000000</DIBI1>
                <DIAB2>000000</DIAB2>
                <DIBI2>000000</DIBI2>
                <MIAB1>000000</MIAB1>
                <MIBI1>000000</MIBI1>
                <MIAB2>000000</MIAB2>
                <MIBI2>000000</MIBI2>
                <DOAB1>000000</DOAB1>
                <DOBI1>000000</DOBI1>
                <DOAB2>000000</DOAB2>
                <DOBI2>000000</DOBI2>
                <FRAB1>000000</FRAB1>
                <FRBI1>000000</FRBI1>
                <FRAB2>000000</FRAB2>
                <FRBI2>000000</FRBI2>
                <SAAB1>000000</SAAB1>
                <SABI1>000000</SABI1>
                <SAAB2>000000</SAAB2>
                <SABI2>000000</SABI2>
                <SOAB1>000000</SOAB1>
                <SOBI1>000000</SOBI1>
                <SOAB2>000000</SOAB2>
                <SOBI2>000000</SOBI2>
                <PARLA_ISO>EN</PARLA_ISO>
            </E1KNVKM>
            <E1KNVKM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <PARNR>0000055769</PARNR>
                <NAME1>INVOICE</NAME1>
                <UEPAR>0000000000</UEPAR>
                <PARLA>E</PARLA>
                <GBDAT>00000000</GBDAT>
                <VRTNR>0000000000</VRTNR>
                <MOAB1>000000</MOAB1>
                <MOBI1>000000</MOBI1>
                <MOAB2>000000</MOAB2>
                <MOBI2>000000</MOBI2>
                <DIAB1>000000</DIAB1>
                <DIBI1>000000</DIBI1>
                <DIAB2>000000</DIAB2>
                <DIBI2>000000</DIBI2>
                <MIAB1>000000</MIAB1>
                <MIBI1>000000</MIBI1>
                <MIAB2>000000</MIAB2>
                <MIBI2>000000</MIBI2>
                <DOAB1>000000</DOAB1>
                <DOBI1>000000</DOBI1>
                <DOAB2>000000</DOAB2>
                <DOBI2>000000</DOBI2>
                <FRAB1>000000</FRAB1>
                <FRBI1>000000</FRBI1>
                <FRAB2>000000</FRAB2>
                <FRBI2>000000</FRBI2>
                <SAAB1>000000</SAAB1>
                <SABI1>000000</SABI1>
                <SAAB2>000000</SAAB2>
                <SABI2>000000</SABI2>
                <SOAB1>000000</SOAB1>
                <SOBI1>000000</SOBI1>
                <SOAB2>000000</SOAB2>
                <SOBI2>000000</SOBI2>
                <PARLA_ISO>EN</PARLA_ISO>
            </E1KNVKM>
            <E1KNVKM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <PARNR>0000055773</PARNR>
                <NAMEV>JOANIE</NAMEV>
                <NAME1>A/P</NAME1>
                <UEPAR>0000000000</UEPAR>
                <TELF1>819 566 5585</TELF1>
                <PARLA>E</PARLA>
                <GBDAT>00000000</GBDAT>
                <VRTNR>0000000000</VRTNR>
                <MOAB1>000000</MOAB1>
                <MOBI1>000000</MOBI1>
                <MOAB2>000000</MOAB2>
                <MOBI2>000000</MOBI2>
                <DIAB1>000000</DIAB1>
                <DIBI1>000000</DIBI1>
                <DIAB2>000000</DIAB2>
                <DIBI2>000000</DIBI2>
                <MIAB1>000000</MIAB1>
                <MIBI1>000000</MIBI1>
                <MIAB2>000000</MIAB2>
                <MIBI2>000000</MIBI2>
                <DOAB1>000000</DOAB1>
                <DOBI1>000000</DOBI1>
                <DOAB2>000000</DOAB2>
                <DOBI2>000000</DOBI2>
                <FRAB1>000000</FRAB1>
                <FRBI1>000000</FRBI1>
                <FRAB2>000000</FRAB2>
                <FRBI2>000000</FRBI2>
                <SAAB1>000000</SAAB1>
                <SABI1>000000</SABI1>
                <SAAB2>000000</SAAB2>
                <SABI2>000000</SABI2>
                <SOAB1>000000</SOAB1>
                <SOBI1>000000</SOBI1>
                <SOAB2>000000</SOAB2>
                <SOBI2>000000</SOBI2>
                <PARLA_ISO>EN</PARLA_ISO>
            </E1KNVKM>
            <E1KNVKM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <PARNR>0000055778</PARNR>
                <NAMEV>LEBLANC</NAMEV>
                <NAME1>MIREILLE</NAME1>
                <UEPAR>0000000000</UEPAR>
                <TELF1>8195665585</TELF1>
                <PARLA>E</PARLA>
                <GBDAT>00000000</GBDAT>
                <VRTNR>0000000000</VRTNR>
                <MOAB1>000000</MOAB1>
                <MOBI1>000000</MOBI1>
                <MOAB2>000000</MOAB2>
                <MOBI2>000000</MOBI2>
                <DIAB1>000000</DIAB1>
                <DIBI1>000000</DIBI1>
                <DIAB2>000000</DIAB2>
                <DIBI2>000000</DIBI2>
                <MIAB1>000000</MIAB1>
                <MIBI1>000000</MIBI1>
                <MIAB2>000000</MIAB2>
                <MIBI2>000000</MIBI2>
                <DOAB1>000000</DOAB1>
                <DOBI1>000000</DOBI1>
                <DOAB2>000000</DOAB2>
                <DOBI2>000000</DOBI2>
                <FRAB1>000000</FRAB1>
                <FRBI1>000000</FRBI1>
                <FRAB2>000000</FRAB2>
                <FRBI2>000000</FRBI2>
                <SAAB1>000000</SAAB1>
                <SABI1>000000</SABI1>
                <SAAB2>000000</SAAB2>
                <SABI2>000000</SABI2>
                <SOAB1>000000</SOAB1>
                <SOBI1>000000</SOBI1>
                <SOAB2>000000</SOAB2>
                <SOBI2>000000</SOBI2>
                <PARLA_ISO>EN</PARLA_ISO>
            </E1KNVKM>
            <E1VCKUN SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <CCINS>VISA</CCINS>
                <CCNUM>-E803-8027-B7SFF4A0PF716H</CCNUM>
                <CCDEF>X</CCDEF>
                <CCNAME>Decoration Sherbrooke</CCNAME>
                <DATAB>20200131</DATAB>
                <DATBI>20231031</DATBI>
                <CCTYP>01</CCTYP>
            </E1VCKUN>
        </E1KNA1M>
    </IDOC>
</ZOMI034_DEBMAS07>
```

````
I have used the follwoing Xpath -
 

    ```boolean(//*:VKORG[.=('1000','1010','1140','1150','1060')]) and boolean(not(//KTOKD= 'Z002') and not(//KTOKD ='Z004')) and boolean(count(//E1KNVVM)>0) and boolean((count(//E1KNVVM[VKORG = '1140']) != count(//E1KNVVM)) and (//KTOKD != 'Z012' or //KTOKD != 'Z013')) and boolean((count(//E1KNVVM[VKORG = '1060']) != count(//E1KNVVM)) and (//KTOKD != 'Z012' or //KTOKD != 'Z013'))```

but it is returning true. Actually, it sohuld return false as the VKORG 11409 and 1192 are not in the set -('1000','1010','1140','1150','1060')

Any help is much appriciated .

Thanks
Sugata
````

Comment: I tried your XPath with your sample data and it did in fact return `false`

Comment: @ConalTuohy - thank you for checking. I just realized one XML tag was incorrect in the sample data - shoud be 
<KDKG1>S</KDKG1> instead <KDKG1>S</KDKG>
I am actually trying to check if all the VKORGs are any one  within this set ('1000','1010','1140','1150','1060')

Comment: Can you please edit your sample data to correct it? And can you explain why you expect a different result? i.e. state what you want your query to do? It's not clear to me what you think is actually wrong. Can I also suggest that you try simplifying and shortening the expression to improve readability. There is no need to use the `boolean()` function with a sub-expression which is already a boolean expression; e.g. `boolean(//*:VKORG[.=('1000','1010','1140','1150','1060')])` means the same thing as `//*:VKORG[.=('1000','1010','1140','1150','1060')]`.

Comment: The sub-expression `count(//E1KNVVM[VKORG = '1060']) != count(//E1KNVVM)` can be expressed more clearly. It means "the number of `E1KNVVM` elements in the document is different to the number of `E1KNVVM` elements which have a `VKORG` element whose text value is `1060`". It is more straightforwardly written `//E1KNVVM[not(VKORG='1060')`, i.e. "are there any `E1KNVVM` elements in the document which don't have a `VKORG` child with the text value `1060`?".

Comment: I would replace `boolean(//*:VKORG[.=('1000','1010','1140','1150','1060')])` with `//*:VKORG=('1000','1010','1140','1150','1060')` which also yields a boolean value. But NB even `//*:VKORG[.=('1000','1010','1140','1150','1060')]`, when combined with other sub-expressions using the `and` operator, will be converted to a boolean value anyway, even without the use of the `boolean` function.

Comment: @ConalTuohy - Thank you for explaining this. I have updated and shorten the XML sample for a more readability.
I have mentioned below the requirements for this -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying your question!

It's hard to give a proper answer if you don't provide a well-formed XML document as sample input. Nevertheless I'm going to attempt to provide an answer, but bear in mind that because I didn't have a sample input, I wasn't able to actually test any suggestions we provide, so it may well contain errors.

I'm also still not entirely clear on the logic of combining the criteria numbered 3 to 6 in your list. The fact that the XML element names are so cryptic means I've got no real clues from that quarter, and although you say "check the following", it's not clear to me if you need all those following criteria need to be true (i.e. that the clauses should be joined with a logical `and` operator) or if it's enough for only one of them to be true (in which case they can be combined with an `or` operator). So you may need to join these things like:

```xml
A and B and C and D and E and F
```

... or maybe you want:

```
A and B and (C or D or E or F)
```

... or something else ... I'm not sure. So I'm just going to translate the 6 criteria to XPath expressions and leave you to join them together:

> If Count of E1KNVVM segments > 0 then do the following, else set false.

```xml
//E1KNVVM
```

this expression will return a sequence of `E1KNVVM` elements, and when you combine it with the other criteria using a boolean operator, it will be implicitly converted to a boolean value: an empty sequence will return `false` while a sequence of at least one element will yield the value `true`.

> If KTOKD = Z002|Z004 - Set false. No need to check VKORG. else check the following

```xml
//KTOD=('Z002', 'Z004')
```

This expression will create a sequence of all the `KTOD` elements in the document, and compare that sequence with the sequence `('Z002', 'Z004')`. Because the items in the second sequence are strings, the `=` comparison will cause the elements in the first sequence to be converted to strings, in order to be comparable to the items in the second sequence. The `=` comparison will return `true` if there is at least one pair of items in the two sequences which are judged to be equal; e.g. `('A', 'B') = ('B', 'C')` is true. For details about using the `=` operator used to compare sequences, see the section on "General Comparisons" in the XPath 2.0 spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-general-comparisons

> If there is atleast one E1KNVVM segment with VKORG = 1000|1010|1140|1150|1060 - set true.

```xml
//E1KNVVM\VKORG=('1000', '1010', '1140', '1150', '1060')
```

> if all the VKORG = 1140 and KTOKD = Z012|Z013, set false.
> if all the VKORG = 1140 and KTOKD != Z012|Z013, set true

The following expression tests the following:

- At least one VKORG is not equal to 1140, OR,
- there is at least one KTOKD which is neither Z012 nor Z013

```xml
//VKORG != '1140' or //KTOKD[not(. = ('Z012', 'Z013')]
```

This expression creates a sequence of all the `VKORG` elements and checks that there's at least one `VKORG` whose value is not equal to `1140`.

The second part of the expression `//KTOKD[not(. = ('Z012', 'Z013')]` creates a sequence of all the `KTOKD` elements, and filters it to include only those which are not equal to either one of the strings `Z012` and `Z013`.

NOTE this is different to `//KTOKD != ('Z012', 'Z013')` which would be true if every `KTOKD` was not equal to at least one of `Z012` or `Z013`; of course if there were a `KTOKD` whose value was `Z012` it would be != `Z013`, and if its value were `Z013` then it would be != `Z012`. So `//KTOKD != ('Z012', 'Z013')` would always return true, so long as there was at least one `KTOKD` element, no matter what its text value is.

> if all the VKORG = 1060 and KTOKD = Z012|Z013, set false. if all the VKORG = 1060 and KTOKD != Z012|Z013, set true

```xml
not(//VKORG != '1060') and not(//KTOKD = ('Z012', 'Z013'))
```

The first part of this expression creates a sequence of all the `VKORG` elements, and returns `true` if there are any whose text value is not `1060`, and `false` if there are none whose value is not `1060`; in other words it returns `false` if they are all `1060`. The `not()` function then negates that boolean value, meaning that if they're all `1060` the result is `true`.

As an aside, in XPath version 3 there's some new syntax which allows this kind of condition to be written in a more readable way: `every $v in //VKORG satisfies $v = '1060'`, but that's no help if you're stuck using XPath 2.

The second part of the expression is the same as in the previous criterion.

> If KTOKD = Z012|Z013 and there is at least one VKORG = 1000|1010|1150 - set true.

```xml
//KTOKD = ('Z012', 'Z013') and //VKORG = ('1000', '1010', '1150')
```

Good luck! I hope this helps!

Comment: What is `\\\``  and  ` \\`  ? Maybe a involuntary typos?

Comment: thanks @DimitreNovatchev for spotting the typos